# ASP.NET Core Web API with Entity Framework Core 7 code-first -- Ignored property in base class still shows up when serialized

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am building an ASP.NET Core Web API with EF Core 7, and am using a code-first approach. One of my classes `PersonType` inherits from a base class that has an `Id` property, but I want it to ignore the `Id` property. I am able to prevent the `Id` from appearing in the `PersonType` SQL Server table by including `.Ignore(b => b.Id);` in the Fluent Api.

However - I **do not** want the `Id` to appear in the serialized JSON `Get` result. Right now, the `Id` property **does** appear in the serialized result, but it

This is what my class looks like.

```
[PrimaryKey(nameof(PersonId), nameof(Type))]
public class PersonType : BaseObject
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class PersonTypeEntityTypeConfiguration : BaseObjectTypeConfiguration<PersonType>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PersonType> builder)
    {
        builder
            .Ignore(b => b.Id);

        base.Configure(builder);
    }
}
```

And this is what the current serialized result looks like.

```
"personTypes": [
      {
        "personId": "73380575-90ff-48ba-b95e-cafaafe79c5c",
        "type": "Artist",
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "dateUtcUpdated": "2022-12-02T19:58:24.62"
      }
```

As you can see, the `id` is getting populated with the default Guid, but I don't want it to appear at all. I don't want to add `[JsonIgnore]` to the base class, since that would prevent it from being serialized in all of the other classes that inherit from the base class. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: **Don't** use EF types as DTOs. _**Just don't**_. DTOs and entity classes _represent different things_ which is the main reason why you shouldn't re-use types like that. What follows are dozens of practical reasons why you shouldn't: e.g. overposting attacks, stack-overflows from serialized navigation property lazy-loading, attribute use conflicts, etc.

Comment: You do Ignore for EntityFramework not for ASP.NET MVC

Comment: `builder.Ignore(b => b.Id);` <-- This does not do what you think it does, nor what you want it to do, and what you think you want is actually very undesirable.

Comment: @dai can you suggest a redesign?

Comment: @sion_corn Yes: simply define a separate DTO `class` and use `AutoMapper` or manual mapping.

Comment: `[PrimaryKey(nameof(PersonId), nameof(Type))]` <-- IIRC/AFAIK this is incorrect: 
 I don't believe there is any `PrimaryKeyAttribute` used by EF Core 7. Use `[Key]` (`KeyAttribute`) instead, and it should be applied to properties, not types. If you're using a composite PK then I'm probably wrong. [Also, _avoid inheritance_](https://boxbase.org/entries/2020/aug/3/case-against-oop/). And "`Type`" is a bad name for a property in .NET and SQL, given it's a reserved word in SQL and Static Analysis will ding you for conflicting with the `GetType()` builtin.